# Spring MVC url parameters format

Tags: spring-mvc

In my web application, I am trying to make an URL accesible with this format:

```
http://host/admin/users/edit/{id}
http://host/admin/users/edit/20 -> 20 represents the id param
```

I am trying with @RequestMapping like this

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(path = { "/admin/users/edit/{id}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET, params = { "id" })
public ModelAndView editUserInfo(@RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) Long id) {
...
}
```

I don't want use the `url?param=value` format if it's possible without config friendly urls.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do what you want yo have to write the following:

```
@Override
@RequestMapping(path = { "/admin/users/edit/{id}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView editUserInfo(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
...
}
```

`PathVariable` is for parameter variables, `RequestVariable` is for request params

Angelo